# How to read a text file and save the data in to SQLite DB using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to read the text file which contains the data as "ID Name Value". The ruby code should parse this text file and save it in the SQLite DB. The DB also has the same number of columns. And, the older data in the DB should be deleted for that row while keeping id as PK.

Please let me know the steps if possible with some code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) library with :col_sep set to `\s`

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach("path/to/file", col_sep: '\s') do |row|
  row[0] # ID
  row[1] # Name
  row[2] # Value
end
```

Comment: could you please give me more information ?

Comment: This code snippet should be sufficent. There is enough documentation on CSV reading and sqlite writing out there.